# excel - Select all dates in column between start and end of a week and insert row below each set of dates

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked through a lot of resources to get the code below working for a part of what I need accomplished but cannot find any information on how to get the next part to work.

Data Set: Starts on Row 4

Column E

10/08/2016

10/10/2016

10/11/2016

10/12/2016

10/13/2016

10/14/2016

10/18/2016

10/21/2016

The code below looks at each date and finds out what the start date and the end date of the week is. i.e 10/08/2016 would have a beginning week date of 10/06/2016 and end week date of 10/12/2016. Our business week is Thursday to Wednesday.

I'm trying to figure out a way to have the code look through Column E, select all dates between each business week and insert a row below the last selected date in the business week. So, a row would be inserted below 10/12/2016, 10/18/2016, and 10/21/2018.

I added the MsgBox so I could verify it was showing the correct start and end date, which it is.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim begDate, endDate As Date
Dim dtmDate As Date
Dim dtmString As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lRow As Long

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 4 To lRow
    dtmString = Cells(i, "E").Value
    dtmDate = CDate(dtmString)

    begDate = ReturnDate(dtmDate, 1)
    endDate = ReturnDate(dtmDate, 7)

    If Cells(i, 5).Value >= begDate & Cells(i, 5).Value <= endDate Then
        MsgBox begDate
        MsgBox endDate
    Else
        End If
Next i

End Sub

Function ReturnDate(DateRange As Date, Optional DayInWeek = 1) As Date
    ReturnDate = DateRange - Weekday(DateRange, vbThursday) + DayInWeek
End Function
```

Comment: dear op, on your if clause, you can also check for the next cell's day. If next cell is also smaller than endDate, you shouldn't do anything. But if next cell is higher than endDate, it means current cell is the last one. So you should add the new row there.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I apologize for the late reply. I was unable to get this to work using your suggestion. I believe the problem with my code is that I am looping through each date and setting the beg and end dates so it will always return true. Since endDate will always be the endDate for the given dates in Column E, it will not work. I will keep trying and post an update if I am able to figure it out.